# How to get results from after stmnt->execute in doctrine2 symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using this:

```
$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT * from tbl_users');
$stmt->execute();
```

How to get the results back in variables:

```
$stmt->getResults()
```

is not working

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about fetching result. `fetchAll()` could help you:

```
$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
                 ->getConnection()
                 ->prepare('SELECT * from tbl_users');    
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

If you want to hydrate your `TblUsers` after fetching data - you can try to to next:

```
$tblUser = new TblUsers();
$tblUser->fromArray($result);
```

Comment: Thanks that is working but can you please tell me how fetch the id attibute from it, because it is not a DQL so i think i am not getting objects returned. so how how can i access results

Comment: Do `var_dump($result)` and see what you receive.

Comment: @user1513613 You could use [result set mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html) for this.

Comment: i get call to undefined function from Array